# Cypher not able to create edges in loop

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to write query which will upsert(update/insert) one node and connect this node with related nodes.

I have some params for example like this

```
:params {namedEntities: [{"value": "value1","category": "category1",}, {"value": "value2", "category":"category2"}],
namedEntityAmounts: [2,3],
articleParams: {"id": "1","title":  "3333"}
}
```

And using this params I want to do query like this:

```
MATCH (oldA:Article {id: $articleParams.id})
DETACH DELETE oldA
CREATE (a:Article)
SET a=properties($articleParams)
WITH a
UNWIND range(0, size($namedEntities)-1) as i
WITH $namedEntities[i] as nes, $namedEntityAmounts[i] as amount, a
MATCH (ne:NamedEntity {value: nes.value, category: nes.category})
CREATE (a)<-[r:OCCURS {amount: amount}]-(ne)
RETURN a,ne, type(r)
```

First four lines of this query are working. If query founds article with such a id, this article is being detach and delete and after this new node is being created with new params.

Hovewer I struggle with next part. Where I want to find all NamedEntity nodes whitch are identified by (value+category) and then I want to connect newly created Article node with all NamedEntity nodes. But this query seems to ingore last 3 lines and just prints out
`Added 1 label, created 1 node, deleted 1 node, set 3 properties, completed after 6ms`.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your query is fine, your graph might be missing the `NamedEntity` nodes,

Comment: That exactly what happend. For mistake my nodes where named `NamedEntities` thank you